# WAMP - Wrong PHP version

Tags: php, wamp

I tried to install PHP 8 on my Wamp config (3.1.9 64bit) and it works pretty well.
But I also need a 7.4.21 version so I install it too.

And now, when I try to activate my 7.4.21 version (or older), phpinfo() always told me I'm in PHP 8 version.

Worst, in v7.4.21, the extensions are not activated for the most of them (like mysqli) despite the fact that they are activated in all my php.ini (all versions).

Any ideas ?

Comment: First upgrade to the current WAMPServer which is currently V3.2.5 most easily found on the backup repo [here](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) Use the link `Wampserver update 3.2.5` so that will only amend the WAMPServer bits and none of the Apache/MySQL/PHP sitecode etc

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest MSVC Runtime specially if you want to use PHP8 The latest you will need is `VC 2015-2019 (VC16 x64) 14.29.30037` yo can download that from the Bottom of the backup repo page. But check you have all the versions updated, both 32bit and 64bit if you are on a 64bit Windows

Comment: You will need the latest WAMPSever and the latest MSVC runtime updates to run PHP8

Comment: I don't think 3.1.9 was compatible with PHP 8 yet. Just upgrade to the latest and it should all work fine